# Angular Js ng-click issue. Function called only on second click

Tags: visualforce, angularjs

I am dynamically creating an html in a callback function and placing it into a directive. In the directive I run compile so that my dynamic html can be part of my angular ecosystem. 
The problem is that, I need to click the link twice before the method in my controller is called. Here are sections of my code

**CONTROLLER**

```
emailer.controller('lookupController', ['$scope', 'emailService', 'lookup', function($scope, emailService, lookup){
$scope.sayIt = function(e){
    console.log('I said it Loud ');
    var tag = $e.jq(e.target).html();
    $e.jq('#lookupDiv').removeClass("slds-show");
    $e.jq('#lookupDiv').addClass("slds-hide");
} }]);
```

**DIRECTIVE**

```
emailer.directive("lookupData", function($compile){ return{
    link: function(scope, element){
        //console.log(element);
        element.on("click", function() {
            scope.$apply(function() {
                var content = $compile(element.html())(scope);
                element.append(content);
           })
        });
    }
}});
```

**PAGE - HTML**

```
<div class="slds">
<div id="lookupDiv" class="slds-show" ng-controller="lookupController">
    <div lookup-Data=true id="lookupDivContent"/>
</div>
```

**PAGE - JavaScript**

```
emailer.service('lookup', ['emailService', function(emailService){
                var self = this;
                var lookupDivContent = document.getElementById("lookupDivContent"); 
                self.option = '';
                self.typ = '';
                self.selectedAddress = '';
                self.getSenders = function(){
                    Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
                        '{!$RemoteAction.EditorController.getSenders}',
                        self.typ,
                        self.selectedAddress,
                        self.option,
                        function(result, event){
                            self.records = result;
                            if(event.status){
                                self.lookupData = result;
                                if(!$e.isEmpty(self.lookupData)){
                                    var html = '<div aria-hidden="false" role="dialog" class="slds-modal slds-modal--large slds-fade-in-open"><div class="slds-modal__container">';
                                    html += '<div class="slds-modal__header"><h2 class="slds-text-heading--medium">'+ self.modalTitle +'</h2><button class="slds-button slds-button--icon-inverse slds-modal__close" onclick="$e.closeDialog();">' + $e.getCloseSvgImage() + '</button></div>';
                                    html += '<div class="slds-modal__content">';
                                    html += '<div class="slds-scrollable--x">';
                                    html += '<table id="lookupTable" class="slds-table slds-table--bordered slds-table--striped">';
                                    html += '<thead>';
                                    if(self.typ !== 'from'){
                                        html += '<tr><th scope="col"></th>';
                                    }
                                    html += '<th scope="col">Name</th>';
                                    html += '<th scope="col">Email</th>';
                                    html += '<th scope="col">Id</th>';
                                    html += '<th scope="col">Type</th>';
                                    html += '</tr></thead><tbody>';
                                    for (var key in self.lookupData) {
                                        if (self.lookupData.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                                            var records = self.lookupData[key];
                                            for (var record in records) {
                                                if(records.hasOwnProperty(record)){
                                                    html += '<tr>';
                                                    if(self.typ !== 'from'){
                                                        html += '<td>' + records[record].selected + '</td>';
                                                    }
                                                    if(key === 'OrgWideEmailAddresss'){
                                                        html += '<td><a href="#" ng-click="sayIt(\'' + records[record].record.Address + '\');">' + records[record].record.DisplayName + '</a></td>';
                                                        html += '<td>' + records[record].record.Address + '</td>';
                                                    } else {
                                                        html += '<td style="cursor:pointer;" ng-click="sayIt($event, \'' + records[record].record.Email + '\');">' + records[record].record.Name + '</td>';
                                                        html += '<td>' + records[record].record.Email + '</td>';
                                                    }
                                                    html += '<td>' + records[record].record.Id + '</td>';
                                                    html += '<td>' + key + '</td>';
                                                    html += '</tr>';
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }

                                    html = html + '</tbody></table></div></div></div></div><div class="slds-modal-backdrop slds-modal-backdrop--open"></div>';                      
                                    lookupDivContent.innerHTML = html;
                                    $e.jq('#lookupDiv').removeClass("slds-hide");
                                    $e.jq('#lookupDiv').addClass("slds-show");
                                }
                                $e.jq('#lookupTable').DataTable();
                            } else{
                                console.log('ERROR Occurred : ' + event.message);
                            }

                            return self.lookupData;
                            //console.log(result);
                        }
                    );
                }
            }]);
```

For those who may not recognize how I am getting my data, I am using Visualforce (Salesforce UI language) also called Javascript remoting to get my data. It works well and my modal view looks like this.

[image]

**PROBLEM**
I have to click on an item in the name column at least once before everything begins working as expected. I would expect that the sayIt method should be called when I click on an item in the name column the first time.

**MORE**
I am using DataTables for the table shown above and for those experience with the Salesforce ecosystem, I am experimenting with the new Salesforce design system, something similar to bootstrap of ionic but only for Salesforce

Being new to angular, I appreciate any suggestions of explanations. Thanks

Comment: Presume you have seen [Dynamic content added with AngularJS click event not working on the added content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26819222/dynamic-content-added-with-angularjs-click-event-not-working-on-the-added-conten); this is much more an Angular question than a Salesforce one so suggest you search/post on Angular related forums.

Comment: Hi Keith, thanks for the response. I agree that this is mostly an angular question, and I am embarrased to accept that i actually did intend to post it to the angularjs stackoverflow. The link you suggested helped me figure out that I had to compile my dynamic content for ng-click to work. The problem I have is an entirely different one. I will leave the question here just in case any Salesforce expert is messing around with Visualforce and angular js. Thanks once more